# Question concerning isomorphism of quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group

I saw a video that tells that if $p, q$ are integers such that $p|q$, then $Z_q/Z_p$ is isomorphic to $Z_{q/p}$. If it is true, can you give me a hint about how can I prove this?

Comment: Look at $<$p$>$, the cyclic subgroup generated by p in $\mathbb{Z}_q$. How many elements are there? Since everything is abelian, the quotient group exists. How many elements are there in the quotient group?

Comment: What's $Z_q / Z_p$?  I'm not just quibbling with notation.  So I'm asking "What's $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})/(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$?"  The collection $Z_p$ isn't a subset of $Z_q$.  Perhaps $Z_q / pZ_q$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the homomorphism:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\\
n\bmod q&\longmapsto n\bmod p
\end{align}
Check it is well defined and surjective. What is its kernel?